# For the torus to rotate 180 degrees around the East-West symmetry axis, what happens?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, topology, algebraic-geometry

(Suppose to ignore the deformed friction and torus when rotating)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTmzy.png]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What happens if you rotate as shown on the picture?

Comment: You get another torus, topologically equivalent to the first one. Rotation doesn't change topological properties.